# Server response terminal line analysis. What is the last part on the response line?

Tags: django, linux, http

The following is a partial screenshot of the terminal where my Django development server runs in and were the server is responding to an HTTP request:

[image: Responses]

As far as I know a line from the screen contains the following information:

[`Date` `Time`] "`Request method` `file path` `HTTP protocol version`" `HTTP status code` `PID(Process ID)`

**Is this correct? If so, has the `PID` of the response of a certain line terminated as soon as the following response line is shown on the screen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part represents the size of the object sent back to the client. This is the detailed in standard [Apache log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html) documentation:

> The last part indicates the size of the object returned to the client,
>   not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the
>   client, this value will be "-".

---

> To supplement: In the Django development server I'm running it says `0`
>   if the server responds with status code `301`

The last part will only log the size of the body and does not include the headers. Since `301` is a permanent redirect; it has no body. The reason you are seeing `0` and not `-` is configurable at the log format string.

The default format string is `"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"`; if you replace `%b` with `%B`, it will log `0` instead of `-` for those requests that have no body.

Comment: To supplement: Just noticed that in the Django development server I'm running it says `0` if the server responds with status code `301`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.