# What is the output in terminal during runserver?

Tags: django

When you initiate a django development server on localhost using `./manage.py runserver` and access one of your pages through the browser, the terminal always displays a new line of output. For example, my terminal output looks like this

```
0 errors found
June 03, 2014 - 01:06:29
Django version 1.6.5, using settings 'testAuth.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[03/Jun/2014 01:07:05] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 460
[03/Jun/2014 01:07:45] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 502
[03/Jun/2014 01:08:02] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 503
[03/Jun/2014 01:08:31] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 503
[03/Jun/2014 01:08:31] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 503
[03/Jun/2014 01:08:32] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 503
[03/Jun/2014 01:08:44] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 502
[03/Jun/2014 01:09:26] "GET /auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 390
```

I'm wondering what the last number in each of those lines is? I can see that there is a time stamp, followed by the request type, then a relative url, and a response code. What is the rest of it?

Comment: For anyone else coming across this question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076422/server-response-terminal-line-analysis-what-is-the-last-part-on-the-response-li) links to the [Apache Log documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html), which I found helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the number of bytes in the body of the response.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense because I noticed that the number changed if I made an edit to my template.